# What's the best way to wrangle path patterns in Restkit

Tags: objective-c, url, restkit

I'd like to be able to specify a string, let's say

NSString * pathPattern = /api/elements/:id/subelement/:type

and call a simple function

[pathPattern build:@{@":id" => id, @"subelement" => subelement}]

to generate the URL path.

Obviously I can build a simple category to do this, but does something exist that handles such things in a generic way, and maybe has additional useful features for this kind of thing that I haven't thought of at this time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, RestKit already injects parameters into path patterns. Internally it uses [SOCKit](https://github.com/NimbusKit/sockit) to perform this parameterisation.

It actually uses exactly the format you have in the question and where the parameter names match keys on the supplied object for mapping.

The path pattern can also be used during response mapping to take values back out of the request URL.

Comment: Thanks, figured that out in the meantime myself. Pretty convenient, though I found the syntax for injecting into a get request confusing (having to set the route for the object type, i would have expected a request descriptor).